# Removing MongoDB Object ID when fetching results from a collection

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I'm using `reactivemongo` in my Play Framework App and I noticed that all documents represented as for example

```
{name: "Robert", age: 41 }
```

are stored in MongoDB as

```
{_id: { $oid:"574005977e356b7310bcdc8d"}, name: "Robert", age: 41 }
```

and that's fine. That's the method I use to save the documents

```
// Scala code
def save(document: JsObject)
        (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[WriteResult] = {
  collection.insert(document)
}
```

The latter representation is also what I get when I fetch the same document from the DB, using this method:

```
def find(query: JsObject, queryOptions: QueryOpts, projection: JsObject, 
          sort: JsObject, pageSize: Int)
 (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[JsObject]] = {
  collection.find(query, projection)
    .options(queryOptions)
    .sort(sort)
    .cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred)
    .collect[List](pageSize)
  }
```

but in this case I'd like to get a representation like

```
{_id: "574005977e356b7310bcdc8d", name: "Robert", age: 41 }
```

in order to send the documents to the requesting client via my ReSTful API. How can I get this?

Comment: You can use Json transformers: [Case 6: Prune a branch from input JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#Case-6:-Prune-a-branch-from-input-JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json transformers`: [Case 6: Prune a branch from input JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#Case-6:-Prune-a-branch-from-input-JSON)

```
...
.collect[List](pageSize)
.map(JsArray)
.map(
  _.transform(
    Reads.list(
      (__\"_id").json.prune
    )
  )
)
... tranform JsResult to your needs
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that the following representation is not what is stored in the MongoDB, which is using BSON, but what is serialized using the JSON extended syntax (see [JSON documentation for ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html)).

Then, when using [`.cursor[T]`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder@cursor[T](readPreference:reactivemongo.api.ReadPreference,isMongo26WriteOp:Boolean)(implicitreader:GenericQueryBuilder.this.pack.Reader[T],implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext,implicitcp:reactivemongo.api.CursorProducer[T]):cp.ProducedCursor) on a query build, you are free to provide a custom document reader (in the implicit scope).
When using the JSON serialization pack, it means providing the appropriate `Reads[T]`.

I would also add that the function `.find` and `.save` are essentially what is already done by the [ReactiveMongo Collection API](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection).